# TensorFlow QAT how to get the quantized weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, quantization-aware-training

How to get the values of the quantized weights or get quantization aware weights after quantization aware training (QAT) of TensorFlow. I want to use integer quantized weights on NumPy for an application.
I used as follows so far, which gives float32 values.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

for layer in q_aware_model.trainable_weights:
    weights_temp.append(K.get_value(layer))
```

Answer (score 0):

to see the quantized weights you have to convert the model first. See process description and numpy application in [this TF example](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_example#create_quantized_model_for_tflite_backend)

Note that you may need to use nightly tf build for the quantized functions to work properly.